# PostgreSQL: How to get a sum of values and the total rows that went into each value?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table, `MyData` in the following format:

```
|id|theme_id|priority_id|value|
```

I am trying to get the following result for all the rows:

```
theme_id | priority_id | total | sum
------------------------------------
    1    |      1      |   3   |  5
    1    |      2      |   5   |  12
    1    |      3      |   1   |  3
    2    |      1      |   2   |  6
```

The idea is group all the rows by `theme_id` and `priority_id` and then sum up the values for that grouping, as well as, to get the total rows that went into that sum.

When I try the following, I get a total column that equals to the sum column:

```sql
WITH breakdown AS (
  SELECT id, theme_id, priority_id, value
  FROM MyData
)
SELECT theme_id, priority_id, sum(value) AS values, count(id) as total
FROM breakdown
GROUP BY theme_id, priority_id
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT theme_id, priority_id, sum(value) AS values, count(id) as total
FROM MyData
GROUP BY theme_id, priority_id
```

Both of the above give me the same output:

```
theme_id | priority_id | total | sum
------------------------------------
    1    |      1      |   5   |  5
    1    |      2      |   12  |  12
    1    |      3      |   3   |  3
    2    |      1      |   6   |  6
```

Comment: Show us your data, not only the wanted output.

Comment: I don't see how the answer is any different than the query you originally tried (I guess you tried something else and not the code you posted).

Comment: Could you please help clarifying this situation? I think that @ypercube is right, maybe you tried a different query… I would be nice to identify what the specific problem that you were experiencing and, in this way, we can know how it was that was solved with my proposed answer/code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created the following sample `DDL` structure in order to work the necessary queries:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data
(
    my_data_id  SERIAL,
    theme_id    INT NOT NULL,
    priority_id INT NOT NULL,  
    my_value    INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_my_data PRIMARY KEY (my_data_id)  
);

CREATE TABLE theme
(
    theme_id  SERIAL,
    name      CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_theme PRIMARY KEY (theme_id)  
);

CREATE TABLE priority
(
    priority_id  SERIAL,
    name         CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_priority PRIMARY KEY (priority_id)  
);
```

Then, inserted the following test data into the respective tables:

```
INSERT INTO theme (name)
VALUES ('first');
INSERT INTO theme (name)
VALUES ('second');
INSERT INTO theme (name)
VALUES ('third');

INSERT INTO priority (name)
VALUES ('high');
INSERT INTO priority (name)
VALUES ('medium');
INSERT INTO priority (name)
VALUES ('low');

INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (1, 1, 6);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (1, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (1, 3, 8);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (1, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (1, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (1, 3, 11);

INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (2, 1, 7);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (2, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (2, 3, 9);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (2, 2, 13);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (2, 3, 10);

INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (3, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (3, 2, 8);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (3, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (3, 1, 6);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (3, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO my_data (theme_id, priority_id, my_value)
VALUES (3, 3, 4);
```

And, finally the concrete SELECT statement with its corresponding aggregate functions that provide your desired result set:

```
SELECT theme_id, 
       priority_id, 
       SUM(my_value) AS values_sum, 
       COUNT(*)      AS total_rows
  FROM my_data
GROUP BY theme_id, priority_id 
ORDER BY theme_id ASC, priority_id ASC;
```

In this way, we can see that you almost had it with your second query but, as [**@a_horse_with_no_name**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822) has pointed out, you needed to replace `count(id)` with `count(*)`, so that you could get your correct data. I have also included the ORDER BY clause for sorting the columns.

By means of [**this SQL Fiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/395e5/20), you can confirm that the results yielded by SUM and COUNT are correct. As you can see I've added `theme` and `priority`, which are relevant tables for this query, along with the required test data.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote but I won't. But how is your query any different than what the OP tried? It yields (both of them actually) the same result as yours. What do you mean with *"you almost had it"*? If he had tried that query, he would have got the same results as yours.

Comment: @ypercube Well, now that you bring it up, you are totally right, I've tried now with `COUNT(theme_id)` and it yields the same results. I honestly dont know what would be the best way to proceed in this case, I didn't mean to take advantage ot the situation. I'm in the best position to clarify this matter. What do you recommend?

Comment: Nothing really. They have accepted your answer, so there's nothing you can do about it. I've voted to close this question as "unclear what it is asking" but I'm not sure if that will go through. Otherwise, a `count(*)` can never give a result less than `count(expression)`. It can give more, if there are nulls, but never less. And I agree, +1 for the effort.